# Format cells if they contain a specfic symbol / conditional cell color

Tags: conditionals

I found a great piece of code by jfbu:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begingroup
\lccode`~`-
\lowercase{%
\endgroup\pretocmd{\tabular}{\catcode`~\active\def~{\color{red}-}}{}{}}

\begin{document}
Not colored here: -12, But colored within the tabular
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  -4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & -9 \\
\end{tabular}
and again not colored here: -12.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I was wondering if these is a way to modify this code, to format all text in a cell, if there is a specific symbol (e.g., '*') at the **end** of the cell. Do you have any ideas how to get this done?

Comment: unrelated but you should use math mode (eg array not tabular) so minus signs get used rather than hyphens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This takes a `*` anywhere to mean red, not just at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}

{\catcode`\*=\active
\gdef\zz#1{%
\mathcode`\*="8000
\gdef\foo{}%
\def*{\gdef\foo{\color{red}}}%
\setbox0\hbox\bgroup$}
}
\def\zzz{$\egroup\foo{\box0}}



\begin{document}
Not colored here: $-12$, But colored within the tabular
\begin{tabular}{ 
>{\zz}l<{\zzz}
>{\zz}c<{\zzz}
>{\zz}r<{\zzz}
}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  -4* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{tabular}
and again not colored here: $-12$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great and quick solution. Is this very interesting. However, I tried to set it up with a tabular including siunitx, which did not work. Therefore I posted a follow-up question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321229/format-cells-if-they-contain-a-specfic-symbol-with-siunitx

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) which allows you to examine `tabular`/`array` cell contents and perform any desired operations on them:

[image]

### Notes:

- All math content should *allways* be typeset in math mode. There is a difference in `-12`(wrond)  and `$-12$` (correct).  Thus I use the `array` instead of `tabular`. If you have mixed content then you can encode the math mode within the macros that `\ColCellNegative` or `\ColEndWithAsterix`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand\ColCellNegative[1]{% 
    %% Any conditional expression here can be used.
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{-}{% 
        \color{red}#1
    }{%
        #1
    }%
}
\newcommand\ColEndWithAsterix[1]{% 
    %% Any conditional expression here can be used.
    \IfEndWith{#1}{*}{% 
        \StrBefore{#1}{*}[\ValueBeforeAsterix]% <-- if don't want the asterix
        %\def\ValueBeforeAsterix{#1}%           <-- if want to keep the asterix
        \color{red}\ValueBeforeAsterix
    }{%
        #1
    }%
}


\let\ColCell\ColCellNegative% Use this if want cells colored red if they are negative
%\let\ColCell\ColEndWithAsterix% Use this if want cells colored red if they end with an asterix
    

\begin{document}
Colored red if cell is negative:

$\begin{array}{ L C R }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  -4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & -9 \\
\end{array}$

\medskip
Colored red if cell ends in asterix:

\let\ColCell\ColEndWithAsterix% Use this if want cells colored red if they end with an asterix
$\begin{array}{ L C R }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  -4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & -9* \\
\end{array}$


\end{document}
```