# Format cells if they contain a specific symbol with siunitx

Tags: conditionals

In my previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321214/format-cells-if-they-contain-a-specfic-symbol-conditional-cell-color/321219#321219), [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) gave a great solution for coloring all text in a cell when the cell contains an `\*`.

I played a little bit with this code, but couldn't include it, if the `siunitx` package was used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

{\catcode`\*=\active
\gdef\zz#1{%
\mathcode`\*="8000
\gdef\foo{}%
\def*{\gdef\foo{\color{red}}}%
\setbox0\hbox\bgroup$}
}
\def\zzz{$\egroup\foo{\box0}}

\begin{document}
Not colored here: -12*, But colored within the tabular
\begin{tabular}{ 
>{\zz}l<{\zzz}
>{\zz}c<{\zzz}
>{\zz}r<{\zzz}
}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{tabular}
and again not colored here: $-12$.

But not here:
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
    {
    X
    >{\zz}c<{\zzz}
    >{\zz}S[table-format=1.2,input-close-uncertainty=]<{\zzz}
    >{\zz}c<{\zzz}  
    }
Numbers & 1 & 2.00* & 3 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any ideas, how to set this up to work with `siunitx`?

Also, it would be great, if the `\*` would stay and not vanish in the coloring process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the * is used only in cells containing numbers; then in the special environments any run of minus signs, digits and period followed by a * is prefixed by `\color{red}` and the * is removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mil_colorcells:n
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([-.0-9]*)\* } % any run of minus sign, digits or period
   { \c{color}\cB\{#1\cE\}\1 }
   \BODY
 }

\NewEnviron{startabular}[1]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{tabular}
}
\NewEnviron{stararray}[1]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{array}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{array}
}
\NewEnviron{startabularx}[2]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{#2}
  \BODY
  \end{tabularx}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Not colored here: -12*, But colored within the tabular

\begin{startabular}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{startabular}\quad
$\begin{stararray}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{stararray}$

and again not colored here: $-12$.


But not here:

\noindent
\begin{startabularx}{\linewidth}
 {
  X
  c
  S[table-format=1.2,input-close-uncertainty=]
  c
 }
Numbers & 1 & 2.00* & 3 \\
\end{startabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep the asterisk, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\newcommand\milasterisk{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mil_colorcells:n
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([-.0-9]*)\* } % any run of minus sign, digits or period
   { \c{color}\cB\{#1\cE\}\1\c{milasterisk} }
   \BODY
 }

\NewEnviron{startabular}[1]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{tabular}
}
\NewEnviron{stararray}[1]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{array}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{array}
}
\NewEnviron{startabularx}[2]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{#2}
  \BODY
  \end{tabularx}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Not colored here: -12*, But colored within the tabular

\begin{startabular}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{startabular}\quad
$\begin{stararray}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{stararray}$

and again not colored here: $-12$.


But not here:

\noindent
\begin{startabularx}{\linewidth}
 {
  X
  c
  S[table-format=1.2,input-close-uncertainty=]
  c
 }
Numbers & 1 & 2.00* & 3 \\
\end{startabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `xparse` released 2019-05-03, with built-in functionality similar to `environ`, the code becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\milasterisk{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \tl_mil_colorcells_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mil_colorcells:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \tl_mil_colorcells_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([-.0-9]*)\* } % any run of minus sign, digits or period
   { \c{color}\cB\{#1\cE\}\1\c{milasterisk} }
   \tl_mil_colorcells_tl
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{startabular}{m +b}
 {
  \mil_colorcells:nn { red } { #2 }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \tl_mil_colorcells_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{stararray}{m +b}
 {
  \mil_colorcells:nn { red } { #2 }
  \begin{array}{#1}
  \tl_mil_colorcells_tl
  \end{array}
 }{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{startabularx}{mm +b}
 {
  \mil_colorcells:nn { red } { #3 }
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{#2}
  \tl_mil_colorcells_tl
  \end{tabularx}
 }{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Not colored here: -12*, But colored within the tabular

\begin{startabular}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{startabular}\quad
$\begin{stararray}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{stararray}$

and again not colored here: $-12$.


But not here:

\noindent
\begin{startabularx}{\linewidth}
 {
  X
  c
  S[table-format=1.2,input-close-uncertainty=]
  c
 }
Numbers & 1 & 2.00* & 3 \\
\end{startabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks like a fantastic answer, thank you very much. How do I keep the * though? I don't want it to vanish. Simply writing { \c{color}\cB\{#1\cE\}\1* } in the syntax you provided results in ugly typesetting for the * (spacing). Is there a way to simply keep it in the first place?

Comment: @Mil I added the asterisk back