# Format cells if they end with an * with siunitx

Tags: conditionals, siunitx

In the following MWE by egreg ([Format cells if they contain a specific symbol with siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321229/format-cells-if-they-contain-a-specific-symbol-with-siunitx)), all numbers ending with a `*` in a tabular, tabularx or array environment are reformatted (color).

However, I am not happy how this code deals with multiple asterix, e.g., `**` or `***` are replaced with just one `*`.
I tried changing the code for a long time, to keep any amount of asterix, but I was unsuccessful. Can this even be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xparse,environ,l3regex}

\newcommand\milasterisk{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mil_colorcells:n
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([-.0-9]*)\* } % any run of minus sign, digits or period
   { \c{color}\cB\{#1\cE\}\1\c{milasterisk} }
   \BODY
 }

\NewEnviron{startabular}[1]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{tabular}
}
\NewEnviron{stararray}[1]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{array}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{array}
}
\NewEnviron{startabularx}[2]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{#2}
  \BODY
  \end{tabularx}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Not colored here: -12*, But colored within the tabular

\begin{startabular}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{startabular}\quad
$\begin{stararray}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8*** & -9** \\
\end{stararray}$

and again not colored here: $-12$.


But not here:

\noindent
\begin{startabularx}{\linewidth}
 {
  X
  c
  S[table-format=1.2,input-close-uncertainty=]
  c
 }
Numbers & 1 & 2.00* & 3 \\
\end{startabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the regular expression and the replacement to use the asterisks as an argument of `\milasterisk`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xparse,environ,l3regex}

\newcommand\milasterisk[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{#1}$}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mil_colorcells:n
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([-.0-9]*)(\*+) } % any run of minus sign, digits or period
   { \c{color}\cB\{#1\cE\}\1\c{milasterisk}\cB\{\2\cE\} }
   \BODY
 }

\NewEnviron{startabular}[1]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{tabular}
}
\NewEnviron{stararray}[1]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{array}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{array}
}
\NewEnviron{startabularx}[2]{%
  \mil_colorcells:n { red }
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{#2}
  \BODY
  \end{tabularx}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Not colored here: -12*, But colored within the tabular

\begin{startabular}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8* & -9* \\
\end{startabular}\quad
$\begin{stararray}{lcr}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  14* & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8*** & -9** \\
\end{stararray}$

and again not colored here: $-12$.


But not here:

\noindent
\begin{startabularx}{\linewidth}
 {
  X
  c
  S[table-format=1.2,input-close-uncertainty=]
  c
 }
Numbers & 1 & 2.00* & 3 \\
\end{startabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]